# AutoMapper not working with covariant interface

Tags: c#, automapper, covariance

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace MapTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<X, Interf<object>>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.B, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.K))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.A, opt => opt.Ignore());
            });

            X x = new X { K = 1 };
            Interf<object> instance = new Cl<Y> { A = new Y() };
            Mapper.Map(x, instance);
        }
    }

    class Cl<T> : Interf<T>
    {
        public T A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
    }

    interface Interf<out T>
    {
        T A { get; }
        int B { get; set; }
    }

    class X
    {
        public int K { get; set; }
    }

    class Y
    {
    }
}
```

This code will cause an exception at `Mapper.Map(x, instance)`, because AutoMapper seems to be unable to find the `X -> Interf<object>` map for mapping to the `Cl<Y>` object, even though I'm giving it a hint that `instance` is indeed of type `Interf<object>`. If I change the `CreateMap` line to:

```
cfg.CreateMap<X, Interf<Y>>()
```

it no longer crashes, because it can resolve `Cl<Y>` to `Interf<Y>`.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You don't need to pass a destination, you just need to use As to specify the concrete type for your interface.

Comment: You might also want to try [open generics](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Open-Generics.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks, it works by adding this to `Initialize`: `cfg.CreateMap(typeof(X), typeof(Interf<>)).IncludeBase(typeof(X), typeof(Interf<object>));`. Put up an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: It's ok :) The As version is similar to what you did, just a bit simpler.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Could you give an example of using As? Because I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/88a7c788124c184ca570d21f4dda4da32cb17a3b/src/UnitTests/MappingInheritance/ShouldSupportOnlyDestinationTypeBeingDerived.cs

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Looking at that, it seems to me that I'm gonna have to use the non-generic `CreateMap`, which makes the ForMember calls' syntax ugly (full of casts and strings).

Comment: Generic maps can only work that way. But you can always extract an interface for the non generic members and configure that separately.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Well, with the solution I posted, I can use a generic `CreateMap` for `Interf<object>` and do all the `ForMember` calls there. Then just use the non-generic `CreateMap` for the `IncludeBase`.

Comment: That's clumsy. And works against AM. Or doesn't work :)